# ggplot2: Exclude legend from aspect ratio

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I use `ggplot2` and `knitr` to publish scatterplots with a right-hand-side legend. The legend is included in the aspect ratio and therefore breaks the "squareness" of the plots, as shown in the [default themes](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/themes). When the legend text becomes a bit longer than "a" and "b", the graphs become "long rectangles" instead of "squares".

I would like to keep the graphs "squared", and so would like to exclude the legend from the aspect ratio on my `ggplot2` graphs. My `.Rprofile` has the following information to force `ggplot2` to produce low-colour graphs with bigger text and more space around axis titles:

```
theme_set(theme_bw(16))
theme_update(
  axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = -.25),
  axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -1),
  plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")
)
```

Is there anything I can add here to exclude the legend from the aspect ratio? Manipulations with `coord_equal` and `coord_fixed` have failed so far, as have the `fig.width` and `fig.height` options. Thanks for your help!

**Edit:** working example removed, question answered below with full example code (sorry for the delay in approving the answer).

Comment: Here it is: http://rpubs.com/briatte/3978

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `coord_fixed()` should do the trick:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)  ## for grid.arrange()

## Create some data with one longer label
cars <- transform(mtcars, 
           cyl = factor(cyl, labels=c("4","6","8 is big")))


## Compute ratio needed to make the figure square
## (For a taller narrow plot, multiply ratio by number > 1; 
##  for a squatter plot, multiply it by number in the interval (0,1))    
ratio <- with(cars, diff(range(mpg))/diff(range(wt)))

## Make plots with and without a legend
a <- ggplot(cars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
     geom_point() + coord_fixed(ratio=ratio)

b <- ggplot(cars, aes(mpg, wt, color=cyl)) + 
     geom_point() + coord_fixed(ratio=ratio)

## Plot them to confirm that coord_fixed does fix the aspect ratio
grid.arrange(a,b, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: This does not produce any result on my end (see end of example): http://rpubs.com/briatte/3978 -- neither in `knitr` output or in RStudio plot windows. It could simply be that I don't understand well enough how the aspect ratio of the graphs are produced in that workflow.

Comment: What about the example I added just now?  If that doesn't work either, then there may be a problem with your setup.

Comment: I must have been terribly unclear, because the issue I am trying to fix appears in your plots too. In your right-hand-side example, I am trying to keep the gray canvas square. I have outlined the surface here: http://i.imgur.com/s7SVuz6.png -- if the aspect ratio were 1:1, the surface would be square instead of rectangular. Instead, the whole plot is square. How do I get the legend out of the computation of the aspect ratio?

Comment: @Fr. -- I finally get what you're after, and have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is what I was looking for. I am still unsatisfied with how text ends up being so small in ggplot2, but that's a more general concern with ggplot2 output. Thanks again.