# R markdown figure legend is cut off

Tags: html, r, markdown, legend, figure

I'm generating some graphs in markdown file, but the graph does not look right in the html file.

In RStudio, it works well, and looks like this:

[image: Plot in R]

But in the markdown html file, the legend box on the right side is cut off:

[image: Plot in html]

I tried adjusting `fig.width`, `fig.align`, `fig.show='asis'`, `fig.crop`. They either didn't make any change, or just made the figure as a whole look narrower with the legend box still being incomplete.

Is there any way to make it look normal in markdown html file?

Comment: Could you put up the output of par()$mai and par()$oma please?

Comment: @andrnev  yeah, here is the output:  > par()$mai [1] 1.360000 1.093333 1.093333 0.560000     > par()$oma [1] 0 0 0 0

Comment: Could you try to place some outer margins by setting say par(oma=c(0,0,0,2))? Experiment by changing the last 2 to some higher values. This value will control the margin width on the right hand side of the plot. It will squeeze your graph though.

Comment: @andrnev Thanks! I just tried as you suggested, but the plot only changed in RStudio not in the markdown file. I guess it has something to do with markdown setting, but the fig. options I have tried did not work. Will keep looking for solutions.

Comment: Strange. I do see a plot change in the html too. What process are you using to create the html? Is it knitr?

Comment: @andrnev I still haven't found out the solution, but thanks for your previous help. I'll let you know once I figure it out. :)

Comment: Did you found any solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(   Did you come across the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too in Rmarkdown html reports, I solved it by changing the plot margins in ggplot2: theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,2,1,1),"cm")). The second 'unit' number was increased from 1 to 2 to allow for the legend on the right. I found this answer here: [ggplot2: Exclude legend from aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631523/ggplot2-exclude-legend-from-aspect-ratio)